# How can I provide multiple value in a variable using, separator - Ansible playbook

Tags: ansible, ansible-template

```
 - name: Application deployment
    hosts: "{{ target_hosts }}"
    gather_facts: no
    become: yes
    become_method: su
    become_user: 'root'
    roles:
    - APP_deployment 
    vars:
      - password_supersu: 'Abcdefg@Linux'
      - ansible_su_pass: 'Abcdefg@Linux' 

    vars_prompt:
    - name: "target_hosts"
      prompt: "Please input the Target Host name:"
      default: ""
      private: no
    - name: "war_name"
      prompt: "Please input the War files name:"
      default: ""
      private: no
    - name: "chksum_src"
      prompt: "Please input the MD5chksum value :"
      default: ""

   tasks: 
   - add_hosts:
         name: ""{{target_hosts}}""
         groups: dynamically_created_hosts

   - with_iteams: 
         ""{{ war_name. split (',') }}""
         ""{{ chksum_src. split (',') }}""
```

Using this playbook I can target multiple host using, separator but if I want to use the same for war name and Md5chksum value also.

In simple I want to deploy multiple files to multiple host with chksum value check, the task are defined in roles already but is it possible to separate the chksum value and files name as well.

Thanks in Advance

Comment: [I downvoted because lacking an MCVE makes it hard to answer](http://idownvotedbecau.se/nomcve/). You claim: "I can target multiple host using, separator". How? There is no such module "add_hosts".

Comment: Could you please provide a minimal ansible script with no external dependencies.

Comment: In simple words. i need to copy many files on many servers, how can i provide multiple host name in playbook and multiple files name also.  it will be great if i can separate hostname and file name.

Answer (score 0):

Regarding your question about [Variables](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_variables.html) and how to

> provide multiple value in a variable using comma (`,`) separator

it seems a [List](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_variables.html#list-variables) will be the solution.

```yaml
['war_file_1', 'war_file_2', 'war_file_3']
```

It looks you like to [append to a list](https://serverfault.com/a/819752/448950) and do something similar

```yaml
- name: Add WAR files
  set_fact:
    WAR_FILES: "{{ WAR_FILES + [item] }}"
  with_items: "{{ war_names.split(',') | list }}"
```

As you mentioned the `add_host` module already, you may have a look into [Add a host (and alternatively a group) to the ansible-playbook in-memory inventory](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/ansible/builtin/add_host_module.html) and the [Examples](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/ansible/builtin/add_host_module.html#examples). The syntax would than be like

```yaml
- name: Add hosts to the 'dynamically_created_hosts' group
  add_host:
    name: '{{ item }}'
    groups: dynamically_created_hosts
  loop: "{{ target_hosts }}"
```

**Thanks also to**

- [How to combine variables?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56110918/in-ansible-how-to-combine-variables-from-active-roles-into-one-array/56112026#56112026)