# In Ansible, how to combine variables from active roles into one array?

Tags: ansible

Looking at "[In Ansible, how to combine variables from separate files into one array?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35554415/in-ansible-how-to-combine-variables-from-separate-files-into-one-array)" one of the answers suggests using [include_vars](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/2.5/modules/include_vars_module.html) to get variables from several sources into one array, this is *almost* what I need but not quite.

I'm setting up cloudfront_logging which requires items in a `awslogs_logs:` array. I'd like to be able to add to this array for the roles that I have active, so Syslog in my common role but if I have a php role, I'd like it to include the php logs.

I think I could get `include_vars` to work for all roles, but I can't see how to get this to work for only the roles included in a build. So if I include the php role, include the php logs but not if it is not included.

I could, of course, include the array at the top level statically but that seems like it is architecturally a bit off as you'd expect a role to be able to deal with its' own logging.

Comment: The link is now fixed

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your roles can use a `set_fact` task to append information to a variable. For example, let's say you want roles to be able to register paths to log files in the `logfiles` fact; you could do something like this in each role:

```
- set_fact:
    logfiles: "{{ logfiles|default([]) + ['/var/log/something.log', '/var/log/anotherthing.log'] }}"
```

In other words, if `roles/role1/tasks` looks like this:

```
---
- set_fact:
    logfiles: "{{ logfiles|default([]) + ['/var/log/role1.log'] }}"
```

And `roles/role2/tasks` looks like this:

```
---
- set_fact:
    logfiles: "{{ logfiles|default([]) + ['/var/log/role2.log'] }}"
```

Then a playbook that looks like this:

```
---
- hosts: localhost
  gather_facts: false
  roles:
    - role1
    - role2

  tasks:
    - debug:
        var: logfiles
```

Will produce this output:

```
PLAY [localhost] ******************************************************************************

TASK [role1 : set_fact] ***********************************************************************
ok: [localhost]

TASK [role2 : set_fact] ***********************************************************************
ok: [localhost]

TASK [debug] **********************************************************************************
ok: [localhost] => {
    "logfiles": [
        "/var/log/role1.log", 
        "/var/log/role2.log"
    ]
}

PLAY RECAP ************************************************************************************
localhost                  : ok=3    changed=0    unreachable=0    failed=0    skipped=0    rescued=0    ignored=0
```